# (Blender Internal Camera Tracking) Camera stays still while empties move?

Tags: animation, tracking

So I'm new to Motion Tracking and have a simple set up. I was following a tutorial and all seemed well and good, but then I realized that something was wrong when I wanted to put an object in my scene. In the footage I'm recording the ground then walk around it in a half circle, but in my 3D view the camera isn't moving at all, and instead the empties (markers) are moving around? There's a blue chain as seen in the photo and I don't know what to do?

[image]

I need the camera to be the motion of the camera i recorded with, I've tried going to solve and solving the camera motion but nothing worked. Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you have at least 8 bundled trackers? Did you solve the scene? What is your error average? Did you use the normal solver or did you use tripod? Please read though the following link carefully: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 then use the [edit] link (on the bottom left of your original post) and add more information to your question detailing exactly what you did.

Comment: I have 8 trackers? I solved the camera, I used tripod to keyframe, testing each one out and the camera didnt move like I wanted. I posted the Blend file, it's really simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If your original camera was moving don't use tripod.

Comment: Please read though the link I posted earlier. You need more tracking points: you need at least eight, but sometimes that number is not enough, and those trackers need to be accurate. Your tracking points have a very high average error. Fix that. Use the Keyframe option to determine the range of keyframes. Use the Refine options. You need a very low solve error, less than a third of a pixel.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Also I'm not sure about setting the keyframe A and B as well as the refine settings. I'm really sorry, I'm just so lost on everything, i just want the camera to be moving and the objects to stay still, not the other way around. If it's any help, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0WhYNfZ1KI exactly, so maybe there was a setting that I wasn't suppose to put? Again I'm really sorry.

Comment: watch sebastian Koenig's series of videos "Track, Match, Blend" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1v-Bf9XOXIg&list=PLK4PLzXGNUJgGxTSeJCTYMiYS1yq8Sz6C

Comment: Those videos are each like an hour long? I'm just looking for a simple answer.